# Problems installing mailchimp3 with pip

Tags: pip, pypi, aws-code-deploy

When I put `mailchilmp3==1.0.26` in my requirements.txt and run `pip install -r requirements.txt` it works locally, but when deploying to our AWS instances (via circleCI and codedeploy) I get the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking mailchimp3==1.0.26 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mailchimp3==1.0.26 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for mailchimp3==1.0.26 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
```

Yet if I run a `pip search mailchimp3` from that server I see that pip finds the correct package:

```
mailchimp3 (1.0.26)  - A python client for v3 of MailChimp API
```

Also, if I ssh onto that server and run the `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` manually (or `sudo pip install mailchimp3`) it works successfully.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Hi @andrew, I may be a bit late, but have you found any solution to this ? (I am among the team behind this project).

Comment: Hi @Charlesthk, I just looked back through our git logs and it looks like we ended up removing mailchimp3 from our requirements.txt which isn't great as we're still using it and are just depending on the servers to have installed it already I believe.

Comment: yes, it should be in your requirements ! Beware of the 2.0 version which as a lot of changes in its api (mostly plural names on methods instead of singular).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be an issue with CircleCI and was not related to our actual servers.  The CircleCI instance had an outdated version of pip installed which is why it could not find the correct mailchimp version.

Adding a:

```
dependencies:
    pre:
        pip install --upgrade pip
```

to our `circle.yml` fixed it.